# Disable chmod in openssh-server

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm trying to disable the ability to use the chmod command from sftp clients. I want files uploaded by users to only be set based on the umask and remove their ability to change it.

It seems like this should be simple, but I can't find any way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not by default but there is a patch. Not sure if your distro has a patched package already but it may worth searching before you patch it yourself. http://sftpfilecontrol.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively if your sftp users belong to a specific common group and shell users another common group, you can simply utilize [ACL (Access Control Lists)](http://www.suse.de/~agruen/acl/linux-acls/online/) to limit who can use the chmod, along with other commands.

Comment: Do you mean actually setting an ACL for the chmod binary?

Answer (score 3):

(In 2023) this *is* possible with vanilla openSSH.

The according request is `setstat`.

So if you specify the following in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match User mysftpuser
 ChrootDirectory /home/mysftpuser/chroot #or else they see their .ssh dir
 ForceCommand internal-sftp -P lsetstat,setstat,fsetstat #deny chmod
```

it will do just that.
I added `lsetstat` and `fsetstat` as well, as these do the same for links and file handles.
You can also add `-u xxxx` to specify a given umask.
See `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests` for a list of requests you can blacklist. Or probably (even better) just whitelist only those needed.

You need to reload `sshd` and re-login with your SFTP client for changes to take effect.

I think the accepted answer should be changed to this one, as the accepted one is incorrect (now).

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently not possible to do what I wanted without a massive patch to openssh. I wound up just using vsftpd instead.

Comment: it is possible. see my post

Comment: sftp doesn't call the installed chmod command, it has one built in. If you were to rm $(which chmod) a user would still be able to run chmod from the sftp connection.